# How to make bottom tab bar appear only on default screens of nested stacks in react-navigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Say I have a [Tab Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation) and each tab has its own nested stack navigators (see the snippet below). Now, I want the tab bar **only visible in the default screen of each nested stack** (like the current Twitter Android app behaves).

The docs has a section for a general purpose [tab bar hiding](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/6.x/hiding-tabbar-in-screens) but I did not find this approach feasible for my case. V5 docs has some more words for a workaround using  `tabBarVisible` option, but discourages it.

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator()
const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator()

const HomeStackScreens = () => (
  <HomeStack.Navigator initialRouteName="DefaultHomeScreen">
    <HomeStack.Screen name="DefaultHomeScreen" component={DefaultHomeScreen} /> {/* Show tab only here (default) */}
    <HomeStack.Screen name="OtherHomeScreen" component={OtherHomeScreen} /> {/* Hide tab here */}
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
)
const ProfileStackScreens = () => (
  <ProfileStack.Navigator initialRouteName="DefaultProfileScreen">
    <ProfileStack.Screen name="DefaultProfileScreen" component={DefaultProfileScreen} /> {/* Show tab only here (default) */}
    <ProfileStack.Screen name="OtherProfileScreen" component={OtherProfileScreen} /> {/* Hide tab here */}
  </ProfileStack.Navigator>
)

const App = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreens } />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStackScreens} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
)
```

How should I modify the navigators and screens to perform this behavior for this use case?

P.S The React Navigation version I use is v5, am planning to migrate v6 though. So, both are ok in a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### you will need to change the navigation structure.

as you refer for a general purpose [tab bar hiding](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/6.x/hiding-tabbar-in-screens)

```js
const MainStack = createStackNavigator()
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator()
const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator()

const HomeStackScreens = () => (
  <HomeStack.Navigator initialRouteName="DefaultHomeScreen">
    <HomeStack.Screen name="DefaultHomeScreen" component={DefaultHomeScreen} /> 
    {/*add more screen with bottom tabs here*/}
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
)

const ProfileStackScreens = () => (
  <ProfileStack.Navigator initialRouteName="DefaultProfileScreen">
    <ProfileStack.Screen name="DefaultProfileScreen" component={DefaultProfileScreen} />
    {/*add more screen with bottom tabs here*/}
  </ProfileStack.Navigator>
)

const TabsNavigator = () => (
   <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreens } />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStackScreens} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
)


const App = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <MainStack.Navigator>
      <MainStack.Screen name="tabsNavigator" component={TabsNavigator} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="OtherHomeScreen" component={OtherHomeScreen} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="OtherProfileScreen" component={OtherProfileScreen} />
      {/*add more screen without bottom tabs here*/}
    </MainStack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
)
```